# Does box-shadow affect element dimension?

Tags: css

Does adding a box-shadow to a div change its dimension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The box-shadow is not considered in the total width of the element

Comment: Never mind, I found a bug in my code. You are right, it doesn't.